# how to increase size of toolbar which has textview in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, uitoolbar

How to increase size of toolbar in accordance with the textview and on clicking return  it should move to new line.the length of toolbar should increase as text is enterd in uitextview

```
 text view which is in toolbar 
my code is  below  

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 200, 42)];
    textView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    UIBarButtonItem *barItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:textView];

    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.f, 80.f)];

    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(close)];
    toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:doneButton,barItem,nil];
    textView.inputAccessoryView=toolbar;
    textView.delegate=self;
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code. It is not perfect and requires improvements but central idea is like that

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    UIToolbar *toolbar = textView.superview; // you should use your stored property or instance variable here
    CGRect textViewFrame = textView.frame;
    textViewFrame.size.height = textView.contentSize.height;
    textView.frame = textViewFrame;

    textViewFrame.size.height += 40.0f; // the text view padding
    toolbar.frame = textViewFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no correct frames/sizes of views in **viewDidLoad**.
You should ajust sizes in **viewDidLayoutSubviews**.
Read more [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW36):

> If you are using auto layout, assign sufficient constraints to each of the views you just created to control the position and size of your
>   views. Otherwise, implement the viewWillLayoutSubviews and
>   viewDidLayoutSubviews methods to adjust the frames of the subviews in
>   the view hierarchy. See “Resizing the View Controller’s Views.”

Answer (score 0):

since textView uses ScrollView, checking the contentSize seems like a nice, simple way to do what you want.
so... to simplify **storoj**'s example:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    float newHeight = textView.contentSize.height;
    if(newHeight < 80){
    }
    else if (newHeight < self.view.frame.size.height){
        [toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, newHeight)];
        [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 200, newHeight-40)];
    }
}
```

NOTES:

- **UIToolbar *toolbar;** (declare in the .h file of your class)
- These are hard coded values specific to your example so optimize it to your requirement
- (newHeight < 80) -- where 80 is your toolbar's initial or minimum height
- (newHeight < self.view.frame.size.height) -- where self.view.frame.size.height gives you the height of the entire view and prevents increasing the subview frames beyond the view bounds.

---

not perfect but build on from here.